# Tensorflow None in Dataset Size

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tensor, dimensions

I am using the dataset API and am getting unexpected None values in my dataset shape.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

def load_seti_dataset(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        dataset_file = f.read().splitlines()
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset_file)
    data = data.repeat()
    data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    data = data.map(parse_records, num_parallel_calls=4)
    data = data.batch(batch_size=2)
    data = data.prefetch(buffer_size=1)
    return data

def load_image(path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(path)
    image = tf.io.decode_png(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [512, 384])
    image = 1. - image / 127.5
    return image

def parse_records(line):
    image_path, image_label = tf.io.decode_csv(line, ["", 0])
    image = load_image(image_path)
    return image, image_label

data = load_seti_dataset("test_data.csv")
print(data)
```

`test_data.csv` is just a csv with image path and label. Images I am reading are 512x384 with 3 channels. Each label is just a scalar value.

Printing `data` outputs these dimensions:

`<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 512, 384, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>`

What I would expect:

`<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((512, 384, 3), (1,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>`

Why are there None values in each of the dimensions in the batch? Why isn't the second value in the batch a just scalar?

Comment: Isn't that just the batch dimension? You get one batch at a time out of the dataset, rather than one record at a time, so it needs a dimension to fit the multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using the [drop_remainder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset#:%7E:text=every%20input%20element%22.-,drop_remainder,-(Optional.)%20A%20tf) parameter in your
function call.

1.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.map_and_batch(lambda x:x+1,batch_size=2,drop_remainder=True))
dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
print(dataset)
<PrefetchDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.int32>
```

2. dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
   dataset = dataset.map(lambda x:x+1)
   dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=2,drop_remainder=True)
   dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
   print(dataset)

NOTE: '***tf.data.experimental.map_and_batch()***' IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future version. However I have mentioned here since you can find code using this function

For better understand you can click on this link [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)